# simple python loop using wmctrl to compare window names

Tags: python, spotify

I'm having a little trouble getting this code to work. basically, what i want with this is to check the output of wmctrl -l for this string: "Spotify - ". If it exists, unmute the sound. If it doesn't exist and/or wmctrl -l contains an entry called "Spotify" (end of the line), then i want to mute the sound.

most of the code is working, the problem is, that GetWindowsPipe() only spits out one line of `<open file '<fdopen>', mode 'rb' at 0x7f7a5f854660>`. No idea whats going on.

Would someone be kind enough to fix this probably simple problem?

The code:

```
import subprocess, time, pdb

def GetWindowsPipe():
    pipe = subprocess.Popen("wmctrl -l", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
    return pipe

def LowerVolume():
    subprocess.Popen("amixer -q set Master mute", shell=True)
    print 'Lowering volume'
    global volumeIsLow
    volumeIsLow = True

def RaiseVolume():
    subprocess.Popen("amixer -q set Master unmute", shell=True)
    print 'Raising volume'
    global volumeIsLow
    volumeIsLow = False

def Run():
    print 'Starting blockify.'

    global volumeIsLow    
    volumeIsLow = False
    RaiseVolume()

    while(True):

        found = False
        pipe = GetWindowsPipe()
        spot = "Spotify - "

        if spot in pipe:
            found = True
            print 'found'
            break

        if found:
            if (not volumeIsLow):
                LowerVolume()
        elif volumeIsLow:
            RaiseVolume()

        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Run()
```

There is an extended version of this script here: http://pastebin.com/4RtTQCtf
I'm just trying to get it working again and trim some of the fat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetWindowsPipe()` returns the pipe object, which is a file-like object.  In order to get the text, you need to call `pipe.read()`.

You should replace this:

```
 if spot in pipe:
    found = True
    print 'found'
    break
```

With this:

```
 if spot in pipe.read():
    found = True
    print 'found'
    break
```

Comment: thanks. but the script is still claiming to find the phrase "Spotify - " in the output of wmctrl -l when it clearly isn't there. There must be a deeper flaw somewhere in the code, but I really don't see it.

Comment: Have you printed the result (probably easiest using `repr()`) of `pipe.read()` to see what you're actually matching against?